# What MIME type should I put for Windows shortcut file (.URL)

Tags: windows, url, mime, shortcut, mime-type

If I want to have a Windows shortcut file (foo.URL) to be saved for the users, what MIME type should I assign for it?

Default *text/plain* causes Windows to suggest it to be saved with .txt added as default.

With googling, I've found some alternatives:

- text/x-uri
- application/x-desktop
- application/x-mswinurl

If I've understood right, the types beginning with "x-" are unofficial?

Is there some standard (or de facto standard) mime type to use?

br,
Touko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using *application/octet-stream* which seems to work fine for me (at least Windows tries to save it as .URL as such as default and not as .txt as earlier with text/plain)